# RDCL 2008 /*Local Query*/

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, local

I am new for RDCL 2008 format. I used RDLC 2005 format for a while and it works fine. However, recently, my company is changing to RDLC 2008 format from RDLC 2005 format. The original report rendering engine crashed. Because in RDLC 2008 format, the connection string and the query string became `<ConnectString>/* Local Connection */</ConnectString>` and `<CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>`

Does any one know how change from 
`<CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>` 
to something like `<CommandText>select * from US001_USER</CommandText>`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

Actually, I was using VS 2010 to create RDLC 2010 format file. However if I use VS 2008 (with SSRS 10.0) to create **RDL** 2010 format file, the `ConnectString` and `CommandText` will be filled. RDL 2010 file is just simply changed to RDLC 2010 file by renaming the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Report Builder 2.0. 
Report Builder 3.0 uses RDLC2010 which is only usable on a report server, not embedded using reportviewer control. MS promises a updated viewer.

Also see the GotReportViewer.com - They have a source for a program to read all the info... Bottom Right of page.